# Отправка письма php. Отправка с разных адресов

Tags: apache, php, email

Отправляю письмо mail(). При отправке простого текста - все отлично, но при отправке html (хедеры прописаны) - отправляет с адреса "Apache [webmaster@site.ru](mailto:webmaster@site.ru)". Почему так, и как исправить?.

На сервере стоит ISPmanager. Я создал нужный мне адрес - не помогло...

Answer (score 2):

вот кусочек кода, который красиво отправляет и текст и html

```
mail($to, $title, $message, 'From:'.$fromEmail. "\r\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```